# Propel upgrade 1.6 to 1.7 capital letters

Tags: php, symfony, upgrade, propel

I upgraded propel 1.6 to 1.7.2. In the 1.6 the generated classes on addColumn the fields was generated in capital letters. Now with the 1.7.2 when I generate the classes, the fields are the same that bd, ie, lowercase. In this way the project not working. How I can configure for generate the fields in capital letters?